# How to declare List of anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2015

In this official [ASP.NET MVC Core tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search.html) they have defined a ViewModel as follows where Movie is a class. Then in the Index(...) method (towards the end of the tutorial they are populating the ViewModel from a simple LINQ query as shown in the Controller below:

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public List<Movie> movies;
    public SelectList genres;
    public string movieGenre { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
{
    // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
    IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                    orderby m.Genre
                                    select m.Genre;

    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
    }

    var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel();
    movieGenreVM.genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
    movieGenreVM.movies = await movies.ToListAsync();

    return View(movieGenreVM);
}
```

**Question**:  In the above ViewModel the property movies was of type `List<movie>` and the query used in the Index(...) method was a simple query involving just one table (movies). But what if the query involves an INNER JOIN with two tables and hence returns an object of anonymous type as shown below. In that case how would we declare a list of anonymous type `List<.?.>` in a ViewModel and then populate that property of type List<.?.> in the ViewModel? In the example below I defined a ViewModel with `List<dynamic>` or `List<object>` and tried `myViewModel.list = leftOuterJoinQuery.ToListAsync()` but got the error as `Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<<anonymous type: int CategoryId, string CategoryName, string ProdName>>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>`:

**LINQ INNER JOIN Query**:

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
    select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name }; //produces flat sequence
```

**UPDATE**:

As @StephenMuecke suggested below, the problem can be solved by creating another View Model containing the properties returned by my query. But I'm thinking if there is a way to avoid creating an extra View Model.

Comment: You need to define a view model containing the properties returned by your query, and project the results of that query into a collection of the view model - `select new MyModel { ProductName = prod.Name, .... };`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, that's what I am avoiding to do - that is to create an extra View Model. I would add an UPDATE to my post above.

Comment: The code you will need to write to make it work correctly with a collection of anonymous object is more than creating a simple view model :) (and you lose strong binding, intellisense etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmm! Makes sense.

Comment: Is there any reason you are avoiding creating a new model as @StephenMuecke suggests? The situation you are describing is exactly what they are for... to "model" data for the "view".

Comment: @knobcreekman I was thinking there may be a keyword like `dnyamic or var` that would do the trick in declaring list as `List<dynamic>` or so.  But as you and other users have suggested creating a new VM is better than doing extra work on avoiding to use a new VM.

Answer (score 2):

There is way to accomplish it without creating new VM, but i'm not sure it is the right way.

First, I'll turn the VM as below

```
public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public ICollection movies;
    public SelectList genres;
    public string movieGenre { get; set; }
}
```

Define a helper method to compose list from anonymous objects

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] elements)
{
     return new List<T>(elements);
}
```

Finally, change the line inside Index() method

from

```
movieGenreVM.movies = await movies.ToListAsync();
```

to

```
   var output = await innerJoinQuery.ToListAsync();
   movieGenreVM.movies = CreateList(output);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for presenting an alternate solution. But as you opined and `@StephenMuecke` commented, it looks like creating an extra VM is simpler than making it work without an extra VM.

Comment: Agreed, extra VM way to go and simple.